# Home server, desktop or server version?

Tags: server, versions

I'm going to build myself an Ubuntu home server for file storage, video streaming, FTP, etc..

I'm not really that familiar with Ubuntu, or Linux for that matter
and am wondering if I should install the desktop version or the server version?
What are the pros/cons?

I've heard somewhere that the version is pretty much the same, just that desktop version contains GUI and some other video optimization and software for the regular user.

But the fact that I'm not quite familiar with commands etc, should I take the difficult road and install server edition?
***If so***, is there any good guides/ebooks about the topic Ubuntu server.

This is a private server, so only I will have access to it.
The whole thing about monitor, I'm not sure about yet. I'm thinking about building myself a LackRack from Ikea furniture and putting it there with a maintenance monitor-keyboard setup.
My main computer is a Windows OS, so I will use OpenSSH and Putty whenever I can.

The reason I'm leaning a bit towards desktop version is that with the GUI, it's probably a bit easier to have control and organization over the system.

Comment: The edit makes me believe desktop would be best :)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you want ;)

For me the decision would be if the system is actually a server. A server to me is headless (so no monitor) and is intended for more than 1 person to connect to. Like it is holding your website or you provide an sftp service to people you know.

If you intend this to be a machine where you want to use it for yourself I would go for a desktop with software installed that you need.

Setting up a server from a desktop is probably easier to do and easier to maintain than setting up a server from the server install. That last one will be cleaner and since a server is about delivering results to clients fast cleaner is better.